# sending basissen

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

Lets say we have this $3\times3$ matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 &−4 &12\\  
1& -1&  3\\
 −1& 1 &−1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
What is the algorithm to find a basis of $\Bbb R^3$ for which the matrix sends each basis vector to zero or to the next basis vector in the basis

Comment: In general, you cannot.  $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ will send $(0,0,1)^T$ to zero, but for any remaining two basis vectors, the result will not send it to the next basis vector.  Perhaps in this special case you will be able to.  I notice that the first two columns are different only by a factor of $-1$, so $(1,1,0)^T$ is an element of the kernel.  The first and third columns are linearly independent, so the rank is at least two.  By rank-nullity theorem, these facts combined imply the rank is exactly two and $(1,1,0)^T$ is a basis for the nullspace.

Comment: Can you solve the equation in this case $Ax=(1,1,0)^T$ for a vector $x$ which will act as the second element in the basis?  Can you solve the equation $Ay=x$ where $x$ is the solution you chose in the previous part?  Do those form a basis for $\Bbb R^3$?